# pouchdb/react, set state value to zero if no result is in the database

Tags: reactjs, pouchdb

I've got a block of code that works perfectly as long as something is in the database, but this is causing the app to crash on first load because there is no result set in the database on the fresh deploy. Right now, if I set the data and load this screen, it gets the result set from pouchdb and gets the doc, then sets state values based on the document indeces.

Cuerrently on the fresh load, I get the error that it can't read the property of undefined for `newBaselineDocs[0]`

I need to alter this so that if there is no result from the database, then I instead set state of those values to zero across the board.

For example, if there's no result then instead of `ldl: newBaselineDocs[0].ldl` I would use `ldl: 0` if that makes sense. I know it would be something like an if/else but I don;t really know how I would do it with pouchdb result logic.

```
setBaselineMax = () => {
    this.state.baselineDB.db.find({
      selector: {
        $and: [
          {_id: {"$gte": null}},
          {ldl: {$exists:true}},
          {hdl: {$exists:true}},
          {totalChol: {$exists:true}},
          {weight: {$exists:true}},
          {water: {$exists:true}},
          {sleep: {$exists:true}},
          {activity: {$exists:true}},
          {heartRate: {$exists:true}},
          {netCalories: {$exists:true}},
          {bloodPresure: {$exists:true}},
          {whiteCount: {$exists:true}},
          {redCount: {$exists:true}},
          {trig: {$exists:true}},
          {glucose: {$exists:true}},
          {oxygen: {$exists:true}},
          {psa: {$exists:true}},
          {alcohol: {$exists:true}},
          {createdAt: {$exists: true}}

        ]
      },
      fields: ['_id','ldl','hdl','totalChol','weight','water','sleep','activity','heartRate','netCalories','bloodPresure','whiteCount','redCount','trig','glucose','oxygen','psa', 'alcohol'],
      sort: [{'_id':'asc'}],
      limit: 1
    }).then(result => {
      console.log('baseline result');
      console.log(result);

      const newBaselineDocs = result.docs;

      console.log('this is basline data from app');
      console.log(newBaselineDocs);

      this.setState(prevState => ({
        baselineRecord: {                   // object that we want to update
            ...prevState.baselineRecord,    // keep all other key-value pairs
            ldl: newBaselineDocs[0].ldl,
            hdl: newBaselineDocs[0].hdl,
            totalChol: newBaselineDocs[0].totalChol,
            weight: newBaselineDocs[0].weight,
            water: newBaselineDocs[0].water,
            sleep: newBaselineDocs[0].sleep,
            activity: newBaselineDocs[0].activity,
            heartRate: newBaselineDocs[0].heartRate,
            netCalories: newBaselineDocs[0].netCalories,
            bloodPresure: newBaselineDocs[0].bloodPresure,
            whiteCount: newBaselineDocs[0].whiteCount,
            redCount: newBaselineDocs[0].redCount,
            trig: newBaselineDocs[0].trig,
            glucose: newBaselineDocs[0].glucose,
            oxygen: newBaselineDocs[0].oxygen,
            psa: newBaselineDocs[0].psa,
            alcohol: newBaselineDocs[0].alcohol     // update the value of specific key
        }
      }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be in a comment but it would be an ugly mess.  The error is expected because `result.docs` is empty whereas your code assumes it is never empty.

Since `newBaselineDocs` is empty because `result.docs` is empty, `newBaselineDocs[0][someProperty]` is undefined.

This is easy to fix, simply check is result.docs is empty and if so initialize with your 'zero across the board' approach, e.g.

```js
// snip
}).then(result => {
  let doc;
  if(result.docs.length === 0) {
    // initialize doc with default values
    doc = {
      //  default property values
    };
  } 
  // do something with doc
});
```